# Django Channels Websocket group name

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

Sorry for bad English :(
I want to create notification system per user. User has own group/room and every notification go to specific user's notification room. Every time when user connect to websocket, user creates the same id of user. `self.scope["user"]`. Therefore only `user_notification_1` group name was created. How it is possible to create group name depending on user?

I use

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns)),
    }
)
```

Code:

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer


class NotificationConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.user = self.scope["user"]
        if self.user.is_authenticated:
            self.room_group_name = f"user_notification_{self.user.id}"
        else:
            self.room_group_name = "anonymous"
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)

    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        self.user = self.scope["user"]
        if self.user.is_authenticated:
            await self.send(
                text_data=json.dumps({"message": "pong"})
            )
        else:
            await self.send(
                text_data=json.dumps({"type": "error", "code": "UserNotAuthenticated"})
            )

    async def new_chat_message(self, event):
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(event.get("data")))

    async def connect_successful(self, event):
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(event.get("data")))
```

**UPD** My problem was solved when I noticed that I disabled `REST_SESSION_LOGIN`. I use dj-rest-auth

Comment: Do you want to create groups for all existing users?

Comment: Yes. It is just for real time notification in chats.

Comment: Could you please explain in more details and give an example. If user is logged in then you create room with the username, when exactly and why do you want to create rooms with other usernames?

Comment: Yes. When user is logged then I connect to websocket where I create a group with pattern user_notification_<user.id>. This means that the user gets all notification to the created group. One group for one user. I want to create rooms with other usernames because I want to notify the user about new messages or other things that associates with him/her